# Question Regarding Variable State in IF Statement

Tags: php

I am a dead beginner with PHP and have been reading through 'PHP for the Web: Visual Quickstart Guide 4th Ed.' by Larry Ullman and have a question regarding something I came across in the book.

At the end of each chapter he has a few questions for review and I am stuck on one of them and not sure if I have the correct answer or the correct train of though regarding it.

The question is as follows:

> Without knowing anything about $var will the following conditional be TRUE or FALSE? Why?

```
if ($var = 'donut') {...
```

I am apt to say that it will be false because we don't know if `$var` has been assigned the value donut yet within the program but I am not sure.

Can anyone help explain this to me so I can grasp this concept and feel confident about it?

Comment: Hint: Look very closely at **the operator**.

Comment: * facepalm * Language designers should pick up a beginners book about their own language and take a close look at list of gotchas the author tried to prepare its readers for.

Comment: Ok, so this is the answer I have come up with after reading all the posts on here: "This statement will return true because $var is being assigned a value of donut, and assignment occurs before the statement is evaluated and therefore would be boolean true because it has a value."  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conditional will always evaluate to `TRUE`  because the value `donut` is assigned, and then the value of `$var` is returned to the `if()` statement.  The assignment happens first.

A successful assignment to a variable causes that variable to be returned immediately.  A non-empty string is a "truthy" value, and is returned as such.

If instead it was assigned as:

```
if ($var = "") {}
```

It would evaluate to `FALSE`, according to [PHP's boolean evaluation rules](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.boolean.php):

```
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) -2);        // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 2.3e5);     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
```

---

**Addendum**

Just to add, as a practical example of assignment inside a flow control conditional you probably see almost every day -- the `while()` loop we typically use to retrieve a rowset from a MySQL result resource:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // executes this inner block as long as $row doesn't 
  // recieve a FALSE assignment from mysql_fetch_assoc()
  // reaching the end of its rowset
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that no matter what you assign to the variable, that expression will always return true, as long as the assignment was successful. When I get home, I must try to see if `echo ($var = FALSE) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';` echos TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: I think I was getting caught up because I did not know that you can assign a value to a variable within the condition of an if statement. But the way you explained it helped to clear things up.

Comment: @Mark Tomlin It will be `FALSE`.  That's the reason the familiar loop `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array())` works the way it does

Answer (score 2):

There is only one equal sign so it will return true.  Heres why:  It is assigning "donut" to $var which makes $var true.  :)

If the statement had 2 or 3 equal signs we wouldn't know what it would return.

Answer (score 2):

It will be true since the $var variable is define to be 'donut', if the $var variable is empty then it should be returning false.

**Example**

```
$var = ''; // False
$var = 'something something'; //True
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be true as `$var = 'donut'` is an assignment and not 'is equals to (==)'. The = operator assigns the value of the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side.The == operator checks whether the right hand side is equal to the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

To make things simpler here is a better explanation.

```
<?php
// To assign a value to a variable you do this
$var = 'donut';

// To evalute the value of a variable you do this.
if($var == 'donut') { }
// Notice the existence of double equals here.

// If you have code like this:
$var = 'donut holes';
if ($var = 'donut') {
  // This is true because any value you assign with ONE equals is always TRUE
  print $var; // Will output 'donut' because you reassigned it.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you really helped clear things up for me.  What I was getting caught up on was the fact that a variable can be assigned within the if statement.